# Bi directional LSTM Regularization how to increase accuracy

Tags: python, deep-learning, bilstm

**This is my model:**

```
    class BiLSTM(nn.Module):
    
     def __init__(self):
        super(BiLSTM, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = 128
        drp = 0.2
        n_classes = len(le.classes_)
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(max_features, embed_size)
        self.embedding.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(embedding_matrix, dtype=torch.float32))
        self.embedding.weight.requires_grad = False
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embed_size, self.hidden_size, bidirectional=True, batch_first=True)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size*4 , 128)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(drp)
        self.out = nn.Linear(128, n_classes)


    def forward(self, x):
        #rint(x.size())
        h_embedding = self.embedding(x)
        _embedding = torch.squeeze(torch.unsqueeze(h_embedding, 0))
        h_lstm, _ = self.lstm(h_embedding)
        avg_pool = torch.mean(h_lstm, 1)
        max_pool, _ = torch.max(h_lstm, 1)
        conc = torch.cat(( avg_pool, max_pool), 1)
        conc = self.relu(self.linear(conc))
        conc = self.dropout(conc)
        out = self.out(conc)
        return out


           
n_epochs = 87

model = BiLSTM()
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='mean',)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, model.parameters()), lr=0.002)
model.cuda()

# Load train and test in CUDA Memory
x_train = torch.tensor(train_X, dtype=torch.long).cuda()
y_train = torch.tensor(train_y, dtype=torch.long).cuda()
x_cv = torch.tensor(test_X, dtype=torch.long).cuda()
y_cv = torch.tensor(test_y, dtype=torch.long).cuda()

# Create Torch datasets
train = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(x_train, y_train)
valid = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(x_cv, y_cv)

# Create Data Loaders
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
valid_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(valid, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

train_loss = []
valid_loss = []

for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    start_time = time.time()
    # Set model to train configuration
    model.train()
    avg_loss = 0.  
    for i, (x_batch, y_batch) in enumerate(train_loader):
        # Predict/Forward Pass
        y_pred = model(x_batch)
        # Compute loss
        loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_batch)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        avg_loss += loss.item() / len(train_loader)
        #acc =n-avg_loss
    
    # Set model to validation configuration 
    model.eval()        
    avg_val_loss = 0.
    val_preds = np.zeros((len(x_cv),len(le.classes_)))
    
    for i, (x_batch, y_batch) in enumerate(valid_loader):
        y_pred = model(x_batch).detach()
        avg_val_loss += loss_fn(y_pred, y_batch).item() / len(valid_loader)
        #val_accuracy = n- avg_val_loss
        # keep/store predictions
        val_preds[i * batch_size:(i+1) * batch_size] =F.softmax(y_pred).cpu().numpy()
        val_preds=val_preds*5000

    # Check Accuracy    
    val_accuracy = sum(val_preds.argmax(axis=1)==test_y)/len(test_y)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    train_loss.append(avg_loss)
    valid_loss.append(avg_val_loss)
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time 
    print('Epoch {}/{} \t Train_loss={:.4f} \t val_loss={:.4f}  \t val_acc={:.4f}  \t time={:.2f}s'.format(
                epoch + 1, n_epochs , avg_loss, avg_val_loss, val_accuracy, elapsed_time))
```

This is the output I am receiving.I have used the BiLSTM model. I tried changing the loss techniques and dropout value but it didn't work. The issue is I guess the model is overfitting how can I increase the accuracy this is the output I am receiving.I have used the BiLSTM model. I tried changing the loss techniques and dropout value but it didn't work. The issue is I guess the model is overfitting how can I increase the accuracy

**This is the output I am receiving.I have used the BiLSTM model. I tried changing the loss techniques and dropout value but it didn't work. The issue is I guess the model is overfitting how can I increase the accuracy, The size of the dataset is 3000**

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbK92.png [output looks like this][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll12J.png [Data Looks Like this][1]